# testing mdx query with parameters in SSAS

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssas, mdx, ssrs-2012

I'd like to test a MDX query in SSAS. I did the following steps until now.

1. I opened the SQL Profiler and ran the SSRS report
2. I found the query I needed (with parameter values) and selected it 
   [sql profiler](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8OzTd.png)
3. I pasted the code in ssas
4. Since my SSRS MDX query used StrToMember and StrToSet functions, I surrounded the parameter values with quotes, e.g. “[Measures].[Return On Average Assets]”.

The query

```
SELECT 
  {
    [Measures].[Broj Pristapi]
   ,[Measures].[Broj Nalozi]
  } ON 0
 ,
    Except
    (
      StrToSet("[Dim Ucesnici].[Naziv Ucesnik].&;[owiefwjhoef]")
     ,{
        [Dim Ucesnici].[Naziv Ucesnik].&[kihebrgk]
       ,[Dim Ucesnici].[Name].&[blablabla]
      }
    )*
    StrToSet
    ("{ [Dim Web Service Web Method].[Web Service].&;[wsINAPBan],
        [Dim Web Service Web Method].[Web Service].&;[wsNAPSBan] }"
    )*
    StrToSet
    ("{ [Dim Web Service Web Method].[Web Method].[All]
       ,[Dim Web Service Web Method].[Web Method].&;[funNN_loadPP30Ban]
       ,[Dim Web Service Web Method].[Web Method].&;[funNN_loadPP50Ban]}"
    )*
    {
        StrToMember("[Dim Datumi].[Datum ID].&;[20170801]")
      : 
        StrToMember("[Dim Datumi].[Datum ID].&;[20170906]")
    }*
    StrToSet("[Dim Ucesnici].[Opis Tip Ucesnik].&;[Bank]") ON 1
 ,NON EMPTY 
    {
        [Dim Date].[Date].Children*
        [Dim Date].[Month].Children*
        [Dim Date].[MonthName].Children
    } ON 2
 FROM [DW];
```

5. I commented out the rest of the lines and just left the mdx query 
   6.When I ran the query it gave me an error "An MDX expression was expected while a full statement was specified."

I followed the following tutorial for my mdx testing http://prologika.com/how-to-test-ssrs-mdx-queries-in-sql-server-management-studio/

Any idea what the problem might be?

Comment: Post your code or no one can help.

Comment: Remove ; within ".&;".

Comment: thank you so much ! although it says, Results cannot be displayed for cellsets with more than two axes.? how can i fix this?

Comment: You cannot use more than two axis using SSMS. here you are using three 0, 1 and 2. You probably want to just cross join the set on axis 2 with the set on axis 1 and then you will get the desired results.

Comment: SSRS has a Query Designer built in to the Dataset Properties. You can drag and drop to build an MDX query in there. That way you don't have to edit any MDX manually.

Comment: I tried to execute the query with crossjoin, but it's stuck in a forever loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you really using this in your member names? `.&;[` ....the semi-colon is reserved for the end of `mdx` statements. Please take out all the semi-colons:

```
SELECT 
  {
    [Measures].[Broj Pristapi]
   ,[Measures].[Broj Nalozi]
  } ON 0
 ,
    Except
    (
      StrToSet("{[Dim Ucesnici].[Naziv Ucesnik].&[owiefwjhoef]}")
     ,{
        [Dim Ucesnici].[Naziv Ucesnik].&[kihebrgk]
       ,[Dim Ucesnici].[Name].&[blablabla]
      }
    )*
    StrToSet
    ("{ [Dim Web Service Web Method].[Web Service].&[wsINAPBan],
        [Dim Web Service Web Method].[Web Service].&[wsNAPSBan] }"
    )*
    StrToSet
    ("{ [Dim Web Service Web Method].[Web Method].[All]
       ,[Dim Web Service Web Method].[Web Method].&[funNN_loadPP30Ban]
       ,[Dim Web Service Web Method].[Web Method].&[funNN_loadPP50Ban]}"
    )*
    {
        StrToMember("[Dim Datumi].[Datum ID].&[20170801]")
      : 
        StrToMember("[Dim Datumi].[Datum ID].&[20170906]")
    }*
    StrToSet("[Dim Ucesnici].[Opis Tip Ucesnik].&[Bank]") ON 1
 ,NON EMPTY 
    {
        [Dim Date].[Date].Children*
        [Dim Date].[Month].Children*
        [Dim Date].[MonthName].Children
    } ON 2
 FROM [DW];
```